# PIC18 control registers

Tags: pic, embedded

I'm setting the Analog Channel Select bits in the ADCON0 A/D control register. In the data sheet it list "CHS<4:0> Analog Channel Select bits".

In MikroC I write the below to set up my input channel.

ADCON0.CHS4 = 0x14;

What I don't understand is the "<4:0>" part, what does this represent?

[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing it..I would interpret from the data sheet that it's using bits 6 to 2 inclusive, of the 8 bit register.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ADCON0 register varies between Microchip processors.  And Microchip definitions vary for different versions of their SDK / libraries.

Assuming "CHS<4:0> Analog Channel Select bits" applies to your chip, all this means is that 5 contiguous bits of this register are set aside to pick an analog input source.  They could be the 1st through 5th bit.  They could also be the 4th through 8th bit.

The notation "ADCON0.CHS4" suggests you are only assigning a value to the CHS4 bit in the ADCON0 register.  In order to select an analog input you need to assign a value to all the CHannelSelection bits.  Assuming the CHS bits start in the 3rd bit position and all other bits are zero or will be change as needed to 1 later in your code:

```
   ADCON0 = (0x14 << 2);  // Select ADC Channel
```

Or we can extend your original code:

```
  ADCON0.CHS0 = 0;  // 0
  ADCON0.CHS1 = 0;  // 0
  ADCON0.CHS2 = 1;  // 1
  ADCON0.CHS3 = 0;  // 0
  ADCON0.CHS4 = 1;  // 1
```

Comment: You might think CHS<4:0>, for this chip, should actually read CHS<6:2>.  I agree.  As far as I can tell, this is a Microchip convention.  To their credit they are consistent in all their documents that I have read.

Comment: "ADCON0.CHS4 = 0x14" My understand is that I'am writing "10100" to bits 6-2 of the ADCON0 register which represents channel AN20

Comment: You should be able to check the definition of ADCON0.CHS4.  I think it is only for 1 bit. There might be a definition for something like ADCON0.CHS.  However, searching the internet I have only found the 2 solutions above for setting the 5 CHS bits.

Comment: Just tested it and ADCON0 = (0x14 << 2); works

Comment: Excellent! You might try @tcrosley 's suggestion as well.  I don't have an up-to-date Microchip SDK to try it.  But I am curious to see how well it works.

Answer (score 1):

Each of those bits are to uniquely access which ADC channel will be used for ADC operation. Refer to the Pin details for your PIC and you will find that each of those AN0....AN27 will be available at a pin. For example,Suppose you want to convert an analog signal to a digital value, you will have to connect that analog circuit to pin corresponding to AN18 by referring to the pin details from your data sheet and configure ADCON0 |= (0x12U <<  2).
[This](http://www.microcontrollerboard.com/analog-to-digital-converter.html) should help you understand better.

Comment: Yes I understand that "ADCON0.CHS4 = 0x14" means that I'am configuring the ADC to be looking for an analog signal on pin AN20. I was asking what <4:0> refers to.

Comment: <Bit 4,Bit 3,Bit 2,Bit 1,Bit 0>

Answer (score 1):

ADCON0.CHS0, ADCON0.CHS1, ... ADCON0.CHS4 etc. refer to individual bits.   Refer to the structure below.

I looked in a source file for a PIC18 processor and found:

```
typedef union
{
   struct
   {
      unsigned ADON               : 1;
      unsigned GO_NOT_DONE        : 1;
      unsigned CHS0               : 1;
      unsigned CHS1               : 1;
      unsigned CHS2               : 1;
      unsigned CHS3               : 1;
      unsigned CHS4               : 1;
      unsigned                    : 1;
  };
                .
                .
                .
  struct
  {
    unsigned                      : 2;
    unsigned CHS                  : 5;
    unsigned                      : 1;
  };
} __ADCON0bits_t
```

Because the two structs are inside a untion, the CHS field overlays the CH0 ... CH4 fields.  This means you can write to the entire field as a group.  This is out of the Microchip library, so your compiler .h file may be different.

So you might try writing:   ADCON0.CHS = 0x14;

Comment: The PICAXE chips are easier to program.  Just sayin.'